# Prestashop 1.7.4.2 catalog price rules

Tags: prestashop, rules, price, catalog

I'm getting crazy about to simple problems.

Catalog price rules are not applied like I would love to see it.

The result should be quiet simple.

Product A = retail price: € 86 = Sell price = € 74 ----> € 12 discount is managed by the csv import & works perfectly

On this € 67 I would do a simple EXTRA discount off 15% so the final price needs to be: € 62.90

The extra discount should only be for a few days available.

I did set a catalog price rule, this is also perfectly showing in the product detail page.

But in diffent browser I get different results (never is catalog price rule applied):

Google Chrome = only the first specific pricerule is applied. ( € 86 ---> € 74)

Mozilla Firefox = strongly wrong = showing retail price : € 71.07 ---> also same discount as in chrome (€12) ---> € 59.07 when I refresh or I buy the product & I trhow this in the basket, numbers are changing to the same as in chrome.... Strongly wrong information to the potential customer!

Edge = the same result as chrome

How could I manage the EXTRA 15% discount?

& How could I manage the difference between chrome & firefox ---> settings are completely the same, all tested in private window & cleared cache ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, let me explain, if you have a discount of 10% for a product (created by a specific price) and now you need to add an extra 10% for a limited time with the expectation of having a 20% off, you need create this new specific price rule with 20% instead of 10%.

The discounts are not cumulative, PrestaShop takes the highest discount by default.